# serving static directory folder in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have below folder structure in my app

> /app/server - has content for api
>
> /app/static  - has images, js and css files in respective folder like (/static/images,/static/js... etc)

```
upstream pythonapp  {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    error_log  /home/LogFiles/docker/error.log warn;
    root   /app;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1d;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass  http://pythonapp;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Everything worked as expected but today I realized that we were using 
`http://xyz.abc/images/abc.gif` instead of
`http://xyz.abc/static/images/abc.gif`

As there is no static in URL, my /static rule won't be honored anymore.

I have read articles online on different approaches but none of them had anything close to URL without /static in it. Anyone had this issue before and aware of a solution ?

NEW EDITS :

I have changed content to below as @shdaws mentioned. I had to change root in  server level too to make it work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    error_log  /home/LogFiles/docker/error.log warn;
    root   /app/static;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires 1d;
    }

    location ^~ /(audio|build|images|style) {
        autoindex on;
        root /app/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass  http://pythonapp;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Now it serves static content in `/app/static/images` folder for `http://abc.xyz/images/test.jpg` url. But `http://abc.xyz/images/d1/test.jpg` doesn't work.

Edit : 
- Above configuration works, it does serve sub-folder content too. Looks like I have some config issues with .mp3 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @sjdaws for helping with this issue. Below config works perfectly for my scenario.

```
worker_processes auto;
pid          /var/run/nginx.pid;
daemon off;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /home/LogFiles/docker/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    upstream pythonapp  {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  www.example.com;
        error_log  /home/LogFiles/docker/error.log warn;
        root   /app/static;
        index  index.html index.htm;

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|mp3|html)$ {
            expires 1d;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass  http://pythonapp;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your static location to be images assuming `abc.gif` is located at `/app/static/abc.gif`:

```
# Serve /images/file.ext from /app/static/file.ext
location ^~ /images {
    autoindex on;
    alias /app/static;
}
```

If you're trying to serve the file from `/app/static/images/abc.gif` use `root` instead of alias, this will append the URL to the root:

```
# Serve /images/file.ext from /app/static/images/file.ext
location ^~ /images {
    autoindex on;
    root /app/static;
}
```

You can also use regex in the location for all directories you want:

```
location ^~ /(images|js|css) {
```

Comment: Hi @sjdaws, it serves /app/static folder content now but its sub-folders are not working

Comment: @prashanth what does your error log say? Subfolders should work fine if files do.

Comment: I did some more debugging at my end.. it does serves files in sub-folder.. but for some reason .html/.mp3 files are not working in any folder.. looks to be some mime type issue

Comment: I wasted my weekend on a very silly mistake.. I actually had two rules for static files removing second one resolved all issues :(